# Regex match giturl with optional file name

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need to get two parts (username/gistid and filename) from a github gist url.

Sofar i got this:

```
  const gisturl = "https://gist.github.com/vanaf1979/329abed564c2ba10eda29a53b399ac69#file-parse-wp-rest-api-1-parse-js";
  const myRegexp = /\.com\/+(.*)?#file-(.*)/gi;
  const matches = myRegexp.exec(gisturl);
  console.log(matches);
```

whithc gives me

```
0: ".com/vanaf1979/329abed564c2ba10eda29a53b399ac69#file-parse-wp-rest-api-1-parse-js"
1: "vanaf1979/329abed564c2ba10eda29a53b399ac69"
2: "parse-wp-rest-api-1-parse-js"
```

So far so good, except the filename (#file-parse-wp-rest-api-1-parse-js) is optional and if i remove it from the string the regex doest match anymore.

So i need the regex to match both case with or without the filename.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the first part to use a negated character class instead `[^#]+` matching any char except a `#`

Then you can make the second part optional and keep the capturing group for the part that comes after `file-`

Note that you can omit the plus sign after the forward slash `\/+`

```
\.com\/([^#]+)(?:#file-(.*))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X5jOCC/1)

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks, Also for the explenation! You rock! :p